# AngularJS: Directive isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to build a chat with Pusher and AngularJs.

```
<div id="chats" ng-controller="ChatCtrl">
    <chat chat-id="1" chat-name="Max"></chat>
    <chat chat-id="2" chat-name="John"></chat>
    <chat chat-id="3" chat-name="Susanne"></chat>
</div>
```

I have the following directive:

```
.directive('chat', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/tpl/chat-box.html'
    }
}]);
```

and the following controller:

```
.controller('ChatCtrl', ['$scope', '$pusher', 
        function($scope, $pusher) {
            $scope.pusher = $pusher(client);

}])
```

Where should I handle ajax requests to receive old messages and Pusher channel binding to receive new messages for a chat-box? In the controller or in the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably in a *service*, which would encapsulate other business logic as well. The controller would then just the service's API to send/receive data and make this data available to the view, while the directive should generally be only concerned with DOM manipulation, and it, too, should not contain business logic.

Your question is a bit too general though, and the title does not really reflect your question (your directive doesn't even have an isolate scope).